# MS Access query multiple criteria

Tags: ms-access, vba, hardcode

I am trying to build an access query with multiple criteria. The table to be queried is  "tblVendor" which has information about vendor shipment data as shown below:

[image]

The second table is "tblSchedule" which has the schedule for each Vendor cutoff date. This table has cutoff dates for data analysis.

[image]

For each vendor, I need to select records which have the ShipDate >= CutoffDate. Although not shown in the data here, it may be possible that multiple vendors have same CutoffDate. 
For small number of records in "tblCutoffdate", I can write a query which looks like:

```
SELECT tblVendors.ShipmentId, tblVendors.VendorNumber, tblVendors.VendorName, 
tblVendors.Units, tblVendors.ShipDate
FROM tblVendors INNER JOIN tblCutoffDate ON tblVendors.VendorNumber =
tblCutoffDate.VendorNumber
WHERE (((tblVendors.VendorNumber) In (SELECT VendorNumber FROM [tblCutoffDate] WHERE 
[tblCutoffDate].[CutoffDate] = #2/1/2014#)) AND ((tblVendors.ShipDate)>=#2/1/2014#)) OR
(((tblVendors.VendorNumber) In (SELECT VendorNumber FROM [tblCutoffDate] WHERE
[tblCutoffDate].[CutoffDate] = #4/1/2014#)) AND ((tblVendors.ShipDate)>=#4/1/2014#));
```

As desired, the query gives me a result which looks like:

[image]

What concerns me now is that I have a lot of records being added to the "tblCutoffDate" which makes it difficult for me to hardcode the dates in the query. Is there a better way to write the above SQL statement without any hardcoding?

Comment: Use parameters for date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simpler `WHERE` clause should give you what you want.

```sql
SELECT
    v.ShipmentId,
    v.VendorNumber,
    v.VendorName,
    v.Units,
    v.ShipDate
FROM
    tblVendors AS v
    INNER JOIN tblCutoffDate AS cd
    ON v.VendorNumber = cd.VendorNumber
WHERE v.ShipDate >= cd.CutoffDate;
```

Answer (score 1):

You might try something like --  this should handle vendors having no past cutoff, 
or those having no future cutoff

"today" needs a suitable conversion to just date w/o time

comparison "=" may go on both, or one, or none Max/Min

"null" may be replaced by 1/1/1900  and  12/31/3999 in Max/Min

```
SELECT tblvendors.shipmentid,
   tblvendors.vendornumber,
   tblvendors.vendorname,
   tblvendors.units,
   tblvendors.shipdate

FROM   tblvendors
LEFT JOIN 
   ( SELECT vendornum,
        Max( iif cutoffdate <  today, cutoffdate, null) as PriorCutoff,
        Min( iif cutoffdate >= today, cutoffdate, null) as NextCutoff
     FROM tblcutoffdate
     GROUP BY vendornum
   ) as VDates
ON  vendornumber = vendornum
WHERE tblvendors.shipdate BETWEEN  PriorCutoff and NextCutoff

ORDER BY  vendornumber, shipdate, shipmentid
```